# Android Action bar in all activities except the main activity

Tags: android

I'm new in android and I'm trying to add a Navigation Drawer (only in one activity) to my project.
the problem is that when I added the drawer I got an error. To solve that problem I changed my app style to Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar, but doing so removes all the others action bar in other activity.

I want to use another style in the project and remove the action bar only in that main activity, if that can solve my problem.
Hope You guys can help me. Thank You.

here is my code:

`<style name="MyAppStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/bg_login</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bg_login</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/activity_background</item>
    </style>`

java code:

```
private void setDrawer(){
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    //drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

the xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start" >

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_login"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: when I change the style to @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, I get this error:      java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: "...but doing so removes all the others action bar in other activity." - Set your `NoActionBar` theme on just the one `<activity>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<activity
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    />
```

just set your theme to that only for mainactivity then it wont show actionbar on that particular activity

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. I didn't know that android studio creates new activity in manifest file with AppTheme.NoActionBar not even the the theme that I did set globally

Answer (score 1):

all You need to do is set different themes for activities in manifest,

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` for activities you want `Actionbar`

and then

`Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` to the activity that contains `Navigation Drawer` and also as AppTheme under `<Application`too.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the style `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` already contains a toolbar. So here you are trying to put an actionBar onver an other actioBar, which causes the error.
First set a style which contains `NoActionBar`
Then set the toolbar like you did in each activity, and just don't do anything in the activity you don't want to have a toolbar.

Also, if you are working with an actionBar and a navigationDrawer, you might be interested in the use of [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html), which will help making a dynamic UI interface.